# Lazy loading not working in EF4 (Relations are always NULL)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

I know that this question is probably very basic. Therefore, I've been checking all the circunstances sorrounding the project.

I'm using a bunch of POCO entities, reading from a database. When creating the context I'm enabling Proxies and LazyLoading:

```
this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
this.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

_entities1 = CreateObjectSet<Entities1>();
_entities2 = CreateObjectSet<Entities2>();
```

I've marked the properties I would like to load automatically as virtual, as read on docs:

```
public virtual List<Entity1> GetEntities { get; set; }
```

However the property is always NULL. When executing code like:

```
foreach (var forEntity in colection)
{
    object x = forEntity.Entities1;
}
```

I can see how 'forEntity' is a generated proxy, but all the properties that should be lazy loaded are NULL.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

do you have any child records in the Entity1 table for your relationship? If not you will get a null Collection instead of an empty one.

Comment: Hi Giorgio, I don't know If i've understood correctly. In the EDMX I've defined the relations as one to many. The name of the properties and the navigation property (in EDMX) are equal.

Comment: Hi, the lazy loaded property Entities1 (assuming is a List<Entity1>) will return a null object instead of an empty List if there are no child records for the parent entity (forEntity).

Comment: Sorry Giorgio, and good point. Unfortunately, there are child records. ¡Thanks! (The entities appears linked in the EDMX)